# Angular 2 installation error

Tags: angular

I am trying to install Angular 2. I installed node 6 ( along with which npm got installed automatically ). But then when I am trying to install the CLI to complete the Angular 2 installation process by running the command, ***npm install -g angular/cli*** , I am getting the below error. I ran the command promt as admin too, but still the error persists. Any help is very much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

related github issue here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14667

btw: Aravind is wrong about @angular/cli. please go to homepage to check this package name.

Comment: Thank u so much Tiep. It worked finally, U are a life savior :-)